# Shell Script crear script alerta creacion de fichero

Tags: shell, script, unix

estoy intentando crear un script, que me detecte la creación de directorios/ficheros/subdirectorios, y que a raiz de eso, me ejecute otra sentencia/comando

Ejemplo:
Lanzar un script, y si en /prueba/ detecta que se ha creado crea un directorio, pues que entre dentro de un if

Lo he intentado guardando el "tamaño" de un directorio, y despues haciendo una comparación, pero nada

Aquí el codigo

```
#!/bin/bash

stat -f /var/cache/zoneminder/events/camara_cara/ > /home/arturo/estado2

diff /home/arturo/estado /home/arturo/estado2 > /dev/null

if [ $?  == 0 ]; then
        echo "nada ha cambiado"
else
        echo "se ha añadido ficheros"
#       stat -f /var/cache/zoneminder/events/camara_cara > /estado-actalizable
fi
```

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías mostar lo que has intentado?

Comment: Primero arranca un script que guarda el estado de un directorio, y luego este otro que hace una comparación del fichero anterior con este nuevo que se crea guardando la informacion de un stat en un fichero, qui el link de la captura de pantalla http://i.imgur.com/DsvpapS.png

Comment: Lo mejor es que edites tu pregunta y copies el código, es difícil trabajar con imágenes del código.

Comment: ya he puesto el codigo, basicamente es eso, que haga una comparacion de un estado anterior y el nuevo y si hay ficheros nuevos pues que te entre en el if

Comment: Entiendo entonces que es solo un script que quieres ejecutar para saber si hay nuevos ficheros, ¿cierto? O, tal vez, lo que quieres es hacer un monitoreo constante.

Comment: ¿Que ocurre si borran una carpeta o un directorio? además: ¿Quieres ser tan preciso como para identificar cambios en los archivo aunque no hubieran modificado su tamaño?

Comment: @César vale con ejecutar el script y ver si hay fichero nuevos, ya que para monitorear se podria crear un cron con ello

Comment: @PatricioMoracho no se va a borrar nada, tampoco tan preciso, solamente que detecte el fichero nuevo

Answer (score 2):

Usando herramientas bastante estándar de los ambientes *nix, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

1. Tomar una instantánea de la carpeta

   ```
   find ./test/* -xdev -exec md5sum {} \; | sort > before.txt
   ```

   Esto lo que hace es buscar recursivamente desde la carpeta `./test`, archivos y directorios, e intenta con cada uno de los archivos generar un `hash` con `md5sum`, luego se ordena la salida con `sort` y por último generamos el archivo `before.txt`, este archivo contendrá una linea por cada directorio sin el `hash` (por que es una carpeta) y otras líneas por archivo, esta vez con el `hash` correspondiente
2. Luego, simplemente volver a repetir el proceso antes de comparar:

   ```
   find ./test/* -xdev -exec md5sum {} \; | sort > after.txt
   ```
3. Ahora sí, comparar `before.txt` y `after.txt`

   ```
   diff -daU 0 before.txt after.txt
   ```

   Si no existe cambios no obtendremos ninguna salida,  por lo que podríamos incorporar esto en un script de la siguiente forma:

   ```
   DIFF=$(diff -daU 0 before.txt after.txt) 
   if [ "$DIFF" != "" ] 
   then
       echo "Se ha modificado la carpeta"
   fi
   ```

Recuperar y guardar el `hash` nos permite evaluar lo que te comentaba, archivos que han modificado su contenido aunque no su tamaño. Lo que hay que tener en cuenta es que para generar este dato, es necesario leer completamente el archivo, por lo que los tiempos aumentarán en función del la cantidad y el tamaño de los archivos. También este método no traquea cambios de permisos o atributos.

Si prefieres una forma más sencilla, podrías evitar el uso de `md5sum` y hacer simplemente un `stat -c "%y %s %n" ./test/* | sort > before.txt`, con esto recuperamos fecha de modificación, tamaño y nombre. El `diff` funcionará igual y dará alarma frente a cualquier cambio en estos datos.